# CSS floating menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a floating css menu. I am using position:fixed to achieve this but the problem is that the menu goes below the footer div when scrolled down. I have also tried using position: relative in the parent container with certain height and position: absolute for the floating div but this doesn't seem to work either as the floating menu doesn't float anymore.

So how can I achieve a floating left menu without making it go below footer div?

Answer (score 0):

`fixed position` will always do that hence the name. If you are not wanting it to go below the footer try `clear:both;` You also can use `position:absolute;` It's hard to figure out what is going on without seeing the code.